# How to set content-type correctly in thymeleaf when mixing html and json templates

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm working on a single page application using spring boot and thymeleaf. I have two kinds of templates; one producing the SPA scaffolding page as html and multiple producing json responses.

The json responses are being sent back with a content-type of `text/html` when I would like them to be `application/json`.

How do I have the content-types set correctly? Do I need two thymeleaf view resolvers?  I tried `@GetMapping(value = Routes.EVENTS, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)` on the @Controller but to no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there are a few approaches to solving this. Here is the one that worked for me.

I figured it out by looking in the [Spring Boot documentation on custom view resolvers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-view-resolvers).  This lead me to looking at the [ThymeleafAutoConfiguration class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.java).  Then a bit of judicious debugging in the Spring framework helped to fill in the gaps.

```
@Bean
public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver(SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine){
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setContentType("application/json");
    viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    viewResolver.setOrder(1);
    viewResolver.setViewNames(new String[] {"*.json"});
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
    return viewResolver;
}
```

Comment: I believe this would require including the file extension in the view names like "view.jsp".  Just a note for those who may not be aware.