# Render a view with thymeleaf and a custom content-type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I intend to some frontend technique that requires a custom content-type as response to a controller post.

I want to use thymleaf to produce my response like I do for my normal webpages.
I know how to normally change the content type in the spring-mvc eco-system.
But it seems that thymleaf is forcing another content-type on my behalf.

Here is the code

```java
@PostMapping(path="/messages", produces = {"text/vnd.turbo-stream.html"})
  public String messages(ModelMap model) {
    return "messages";
  }
```

I've found this:
https://github.com/brunodrugowick/hotwire-springboot-thymeleaf-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/dev/drugowick/hotwirespringbootthymeleafsample/config/ThymeleafConfig.java

But I'd rather select my content-type by hand. Is there a way?

Comment: Did you figure out an answer in the end? I came across this similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57073434/how-to-set-content-type-correctly-in-thymeleaf-when-mixing-html-and-json-templat

Comment: I did excactly what your message propose.
Promote your comment to an answer and I'll flag it as an answer